# Time convention vs time domain, what is the difference?

Tags: time, terminology, conventions

I really think those are the same thing, but couldn't be so sure.

Is there any difference between time convention and time domain?

For example: "wave propagates along x direction with $e^{jwt}$ time convention"

Here, does "time convention" mean time domain?

($e^{jwt}$: $t$ here means time)

Comment: You will need to give us more context. Neither of these are standard phrases, so the meaning will depend on what context they are being used in.

Comment: @DJClayworth I edited the question based on your comments, thanks

Comment: This is about physics, not English.

Comment: In math and physics, the [domain of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of is the set of all inputs, and it is very common to refer to a function as being in the [time domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_domain) if it is a function of time (that is, it accepts all time values as inputs).  I have never heard of "time convention" in a physics context and it has no meaning to me - where did you get that phrase from?

Comment: This isn't a basic language question, it is a technical one. As such, it is more appropriate for a technical SE site (such as Physics) where people with knowledge of these technical terms can be found.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - The use of seconds, minutes, hours etc is a time convention.

Answer (score 1):

The terms are not exactly equivalent, although both likely hold in this context.

To *work in the **[time domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_domain)*** is (broadly) to consider a signal's strength as it changes as a function of varying time (as opposed to varying frequency, for example). Parametrizing a signal in terms of *e^jwt* means working in the time domain because one can plug in the time *t* (in addition to the signal frequency *w* and probably a prefactor as well) and obtain the signal amplitude.

The phrase of interest, however, refers to a ***time convention***. This is not a field-specific term but refers simply to the convention used to express the signal as a function of time. Here, the [complex exponential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinusoidal_plane_wave#Complex_exponential_form) is used, where *j* is the imaginary number. Another option is the [sinusoid form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave#General_form), with the two being related through [Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#In_physics)). Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

No they aren't the same thing. The following explanation is from a DoD technical document.

> [image: Blockquote]

https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA305743.pdf

The idea here is that there are multiple transforms from the frequency domain to the time domain, and you need to have a compact notation for handling the transforms. The time convention is how that time term is rendered in the time domain.